# WPF: Mouse left button click and hold down handling

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

How do I repetitively perform an action when the mouse left button is pressed and held down in WPF?

The following event handler for the UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event does not get the job done:

```
private void BaseButtonRight_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           // keep performing action while mouse left button is pressed.  
           // Checking e.ButtonState works only for one click

        }
```

Execution does not even get into the while loop and handler is called when the left mouse button is released!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why not use a RepeatButton?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746649(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @GONeale, unless the OP isn't using a button...
I'm having the same issue and I'm not clicking on a button so this answer does not help me.  I'll be using the background thread answer.  But yes, the OP should select an answer or post his own answer and select that one.

Comment: Boy, forget context under which question was asked but will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start a BackroundWorker which exits when the mouse has been released.  Set a flag with the mouse up event and also check periodically in the BackgroundWorker DoWork function.  Make sure you use lock { } around accessing the flag.

**Edit:** in case you want to access something on the UI thread, use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, for example:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
{
    ComboBoxItem selItem = ComboboxConnectString.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (selItem != null && selItem.Tag is string)
        ComboboxConnectString.Text = (string)selItem.Tag;
}));
```

Comment: Work that needs to be done involves manipulating with a UI element's RenderTransform.  Using a BackgroundWorker is looking challenging..  BackgroundWorker.DoWork will basically sleep but if I marshaling to UI thread, how do I call BackgroundWorker.DoWork again?

Comment: When you want to call back into the UI thread to modify the RenderTransform, do so with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke (I edited my post to include a sample). The modification will then execute in the UI thread while you continue to loop. This the same method everyone uses to perform a background action while updating a progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Run a thread until MouseLeftButtonUp is fired.